# Website not blocked in Python Requests only when Charles is open

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, http-status-code-403, charles-proxy

I am attempting to make a request to create an account on http://nike.com/launch using Python requests.

I do have a valid _abck cookie that I send with the request, but it is still returning 403.

Also, I have tried to use both http/1.1 and http/2 protocols when making these requests as some suggested and it still returns 403.

I know my IP isn't blocked.

However, if I open Charles on my computer while sending the request, it will not return 403. How can I send this request successfully with Charles not open?

CODE: 
`

```
urlios='https://s3.nikecdn.com/access/users/v1?appVersion=436&experienceVersion=362&uxid=com.nike.commerce.snkrs.ios&locale=zh_CN&backendEnvironment=identity&browser=Apple%20Computer%2C%20Inc.&os=undefined&mobile=true&native=true&visit=1&visitor=c49d90b9-abee-4643-bf63-6a94c492ccbb&language=zh_CN'
headersios = {
    'Host':'s3.nikecdn.com',
    'Accept':'*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language':'zh-cn',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Origin':'https://s3.nikecdn.com',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15B93',
    'Referer':'https://s3.nikecdn.com/unite/mobile.html?mid=49472818488481869914233501674662902686?iOSSDKVersion=2.4.2&clientId=G64vA0b95ZruUtGk1K0FkAgaO3Ch30sj&uxId=com.nike.commerce.snkrs.ios&view=none&locale=en_GB&backendEnvironment=identity',
    'X-NewRelic-ID':'VQYGVF5SCBADUVBRBgAGVg==',
    'cookie':'_abck={}'.format(rPost.cookies['_abck']),
}
jsonios={
    "country": "US",
    "firstName": 'appleseed',
    "gender": "M",
    "lastName": 'john',
    "locale": "en_US",
    "password": 'Testpassword123',
    "receiveEmail": 'true',
    "registrationSiteId": "snkrsios",
    "welcomeEmailTemplate": "TSD_PROF_MS_WELC_T0_GENERIC_V1.0",
    "emailAddress": 'randomemail123@gmail.com',
    "dateOfBirth": "{}-{}-{}".format(randint(1955,1995),randint(10,12),randint(10,30)),
    "username": 'randomemail123@gmail.com',
    "account": {
        "email": 'randomemail123@gmail.com',
        "passwordSettings": {
            "password": "Testpassword123",
            "passwordConfirm": "Testpassword123"
        }
    }
}
aR = s.post(url=urlios,json=jsonios,headers=headersios,verify=False).text
print(aR)
```

`

Comment: What is `s`? Is that `Selenium`?

Comment: @cwallenpoole s is requests.Session()